# Migrating WAS 6.1 to WAS 7.0 applications ibm-application-bnd.xml not found in ear

Tags: websphere-7

I am trying to migrate a 6.1 faces web adf app to WAS 7.

When I run the server with resources on the server it deploys but takes for ever. I want to be able to use resources in the workspace option but when I deploy the console spits out

```
Could not load resource "META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference
```

This error is all well and good but There is no META-INF folder in my ear project and I can't find the xml file anywhere. So how is my WAS 7.0 server finding when its not even showing up in the project? I looked on the file system too and can't find it anywhere.